# Google Analytics 4 API keep getting error "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to use GA4 API with PHP to pull some data from Google API.
So i found original example from Google how to do that located here (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)
Process pretty straight forward since i was doing similar steps with Google Analytics 3 and it was working.
Process involved:

1. Created service account at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Enabled API at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/analytics.googleapis.com
3. Created key for service account and downloaded json file contains credentials.
4. Added service account to Google Analytics 4 Property with Admin permission.
5. Got property ID that looks like 9 digits number : "123456789"

I tried their PHP script (located above in their link) and i was keep getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ]
```

So i thought maybe something wrong with PHP script so I got python from Google sample page. Same error.

I have tried everything, like literally everything , i even waited couple hours since i thought maybe keys needs some time to work, but no luck.